# Why do my players want kittens?

Tags: natural-resources, games

I'm designing a board game based on this old riddle:

As I was going to St. Ives
I met a man with seven wives.
Each wife had seven sacks;
Each sack had seven cats;
Each cat had seven kits.
Kits, cats, sacks and wives, how many were going to St. Ives?

the objective being, obviously, to be the first to get 2,401 kittens (not really).

The setting is a rather romanticised pre-industrial East Anglia. In this setting, what would be the cash value of a kitten or a cat relative to an agricultural worker's daily pay?

Comment: This feels a lot like idea generation, which is not something WorldBuilding.SE likes to do.  We admittedly skirt the line (since so much of WB is creative work), but when the question is open ended like this, and provides little way of judging how good an answer is, it starts to turn into a list question.  Can you think of any way to adjust this to make it into a question that doesn't encourage listing?

Comment: A better question is why wouldn't they want kittens? Just look at them! https://www.google.com/search?q=cute+kitten+pictures&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS730US730&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjzPbu4MbYAhUHMt8KHcvvBXwQ_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=710

Comment: They could be testing the hypothesis that they live in a simulation run in Dwarf Fortress ....

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for non-code content.

Comment: Thanks, @Mołot. I didn't know about the two spaces at the end of the line method of formatting.

Comment: @CortAmmon, hopefully this is a better question?

Comment: It's considered poor form to edit a question such that it invalidates existing answers. Your current question is more about historical fact than about building a fictional world. If you want to know about the price of cats relative to worker pay I'd ask that question on [history.se]

Comment: @sphennings Having just been through the ringer on this, I'm not sure its fair to accuse a questioner of changing the question when the original is attracting close votes. I'm certain the original question would have been closed, so anyone who answered it (sorry @Will) is probably out of luck if it gets changed to avoid closure.

Comment: @kingledion It's been touched on in other discussions what to do when a question is edited to prevent it from being closed after it has an answer and I don't remember a good solution being proposed besides put questions on hold quickly and don't answer questions you think are going to be closed. Both of those while good ideas don't solve the core problem. I think this problem is one we should come up with a solution for. Perhaps it's time to bring it up as a question on meta.

Comment: Only *one* was definitively going to St Ives - "As *I* was going to St Ives..."  The man, his wives, sacks, cats and kittens could have been coming from St Ives or just sitting on the side of the road for all we know.

Comment: As for the cash value of a kitten in pre-industrial East-Anglia... zero or less.  At that point in time, cats were, if not demonised as they were during the time of the black death, not as popular as they are now.  With their prolific breeding cycle, they would be plentiful and easily obtained, if for some strange reason you actually wanted one.

Answer (score 2):

**They do not want the kittens.  That is why the kittens are in sacks.**

http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/whodathunkit-drowning-kittens-a-bad-thing-now.250267057/

> On Tuesday, a Fannin County man was arrested on an animal cruelty
>   charge in connection with the drowning of four kittens in a northeast
>   Collin County creek. Prosecution of such cases is rare because
>   witnesses don't usually come forward.
>
> Earl Rutledge, 62, of Trenton was charged after a bystander said she
>   saw a man chuck a box full of kittens over a bridge and took down his
>   license plate number.
>
> If convicted, Mr. Rutledge, who owns a machine shop in McKinney,
>   could face a maximum penalty of two years in jail and a $10,000 fine.
>   Out on bail, Mr. Rutledge could not be reached for comment.
>
> The case has raised the ire of animal welfare activists, but some
>   wonder whether he was caught in changing mores.
>
> Robert "Mike" Black, 55, a Collin County farmer who lives between
>   McKinney and Melissa, said drowning cats was not unusual in the past.
>
> "A lot of people did drown them because they had so many," he said.
>   "They'd put them in a sack and throw some bricks in there and throw
>   them in the tank or whatever."
>
> He said barn cats were a popular way to chase rats away. But when the
>   number of cats grew too large, people didn't know what else to do with
>   them.
>
> There was "no such thing as the SPCA in the country" and sterilizing
>   a cat or dog "was unheard of," he said.
>
> So the animals were destroyed.

Comment: How'd this guy end up with 2400 extra cats in need of drowning? That sounds like a more interesting story than whatever was happening in St. Ives.